# file is corrupt or is in the process of creation

Tags: beamer

While building my beamer template, an error window pops up, saying `File is corrupted`.

All this happened after adding a new frame. Code is given below.

```
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \subsystem\item[2.]{DESIGN OF BUCK-BOOST CONVERTER.}
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item $D=\dfrac{V_{dc}}{{V_{dc}+ V_{pv}}=0.4$
    \item $ F_{sw}= 20kHz $.
    \item $I_{l}= I_{dc}+I{pv}= 48A.$
    \item $ P=4 $
    \item $ N_{rated}= 2500 rpm $.
    \item $ N = 1000 rpm $.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}`
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I don't see anything wrong in your code, except maybe for the `\subsystem` command... ? Anyway, it is impossible to tell for sure, since the snippet you provide can not be compiled as it is : it is lacking the preamble (from `\documentclass{...}` to `\begin{document}`) and the `\end{document}`.

Comment: if you are using `enumitem` package, beamer is not compatible with it.

Answer (score 4):

There are several mistakes in the code.

1. Removed `\subsystem`, whatever it should do.
2. One `{` removed in:

   `\item $D=\dfrac{V_{dc}}{  ->{<-   V_{dc}+ V_{pv}}=0.4$`
3. Text after the \end{frame} removed. (probably a typo)

The following example compiles:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item[2.]{DESIGN OF BUCK-BOOST CONVERTER.}
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item $D=\dfrac{V_{dc}}{V_{dc}+ V_{pv}}=0.4$
    \item $ F_{sw}= 20kHz $.
    \item $I_{l}= I_{dc}+I{pv}= 48A.$
    \item $ P=4 $
    \item $ N_{rated}= 2500 rpm $.
    \item $ N = 1000 rpm $.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Please provide an example like this, so that we can reproduce the error and solve it.

Remark: I advise to write units (e.g. kHz) or indices/labels on physical quantities (dc, pv) non-cursive. You can either do that manually with `\operatorname{kHz}` or with packages e.g. `siunitx`.

Answer (score 0):

No error in using \subsystem.
There is an additional { which takes compilation to non stop mode.

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \subsystem\item[2.]{DESIGN OF BUCK-BOOST CONVERTER.}
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item $D=\dfrac{V_{dc}}{V_{dc}+ V_{pv}}=0.4$
    \item $ F_{sw}= 20kHz $.
    \item $I_{l}= I_{dc}+I{pv}= 48A.$
    \item $ P=4 $
    \item $ N_{rated}= 2500 rpm $.
    \item $ N = 1000 rpm $.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}`

Try this. hope this solves your problem.

Comment: P. Siehr already pointed out the superfluous `{` in his answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376871/36296